# Configuration Section Designer alternative

Tags: visual-studio-2010, web-config, app-config, configuration-files, config-designer-csd

The project Configuration Section Designer http://csd.codeplex.com is such a great tool but now I've moved to VS2010 (forced actually) and it doesn't support 2010. I use this tool a great deal but now I can't and I have a ton of config stuff to write.

Is there an alternative to this tool that will work with VS2010?

I'm hoping for a good solution and not having to do a project in VS2008 and manually import the generated files. Ugh, the thought of using appSettings to store configuration is just horrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open discussion regrading this matter.

currently it seems like there is no formal version that is built for vs2010.

more information here : http://csd.codeplex.com/discussions/73703?ProjectName=csd

Comment: +1 thanks but i've already seen that. Just hacks at best. I'm hoping for a working made for 2010 version.

Comment: There is a working release for 2010. Furthermore there is an unofficial build for 2013 distributed directly by the author though a discussion thread. https://csd.codeplex.com/discussions/459444

Answer (score 3):

I was recently added as a contributor to this project (andym1978). I was able to fix the code to support VisualStudio 2010. We want to do more testing before releasing to the official 2.0 downloads area, but I've uploaded an unofficial 2.0 release 
[HERE](http://csd.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Installation%20Visual%20Studio%202010). Please report bugs to the issues page and I will get to them ASAP.

Comment: bout time! I tried another add-in called Configuration Generation Designer or something like that and I couldnt get it to work.

Comment: Thank you sir. This project is a hidden Gem, and your work for the community is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The version for VS 2010 is now available. 
http://csd.codeplex.com/